# React/Material UI Table not displaying header in bold

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem understanding default behaviour of Material UI Tables.

The problem lies in the automatic rendering of the table header.

This sanbox example works fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-owhex?file=/demo.js

i.e. that with absolutely no style definition by default the header is displayed in a nice bold.

In my app I am doing absolutely the same thing:

```
    <TableContainer>
        <Table>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Title 1</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Title 2</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Title 3</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>{field1}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{field2}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{field3}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

No style
No css
No "nothing"

And the header does not render in bold "automatically"

What makes the default "just work" in the sandbox, that I might not have?

I would like to understand, not just "glue on" a style in order to have it work.

Comment: Please post the sandbox link for your version as well.